# Differentiable map conserving geodetic lines which is no isometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am looking for a differentiable map $f: S^n\rightarrow S^n$, which conserves the geodetic lines of the standard metric on $S^n$, but is no isometry.

The geodetic lines on $S^n$ should be the great circles, I think.

Unfortunately, I was only able to think of examples, which are not well-defined...

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: If you take $n=1$ there really is no challenge. Is the question put for $n>1$?

Comment: Im am inerested in all cases for arbitrary $n\in \mathbb{N} $

Comment: Which takes each geodesic line to itself, or which maps geodesic lines to geodesic lines?

Comment: Does the map need to be invertible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S^n$ can be identified with $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}/\mathbb{R}_+$ (where $\mathbb{R}_+$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ by multiplication). Geodesics come from $2$-dimensional vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. The group $GL(n+1,\mathbb{R})$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}/\mathbb{R}_+$ and maps geodesics to geodesics. If you take a matrix $A\in GL(n+1,\mathbb{R})$ which is not a constant multiple of an orthogonal matrix, then its action does not preserve the metric.

Comment: very nice! (characters)